# Spring Roo + gvNIX + Typical Security Change welcome page to index.jspx when not logged in

Tags: spring-security, spring-roo, gvnix

I want to display a general home page (index.jspx) when someone visits my site. This site is build with Spring Roo / gvNIX and using Typical security.

Default however, as long as a user is not logged in, the login.jspx page is shown and not the index.jspx page, see illustration with the Petclinic site, https://petclinic-gvnix.rhcloud.com.

When visiting my site I want to welcome a user with welcome and some general information.

I will illustrate my question with the sample gvNIX Petclinic application.
When you go to this site with https://petclinic-gvnix.rhcloud.com
you get will be reat https://petclinic-gvnix.rhcloud.com/login

After logging in you get at the main page: https://petclinic-gvnix.rhcloud.com. Actually this is index.jspx.

Seems simple, yet could not find an answer.

Changes I made, without effect are:

views.xml

Changed the definition extends="**default**" to definition extends="**public**"

```
<definition extends="public" name="index">
    <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/views/index.jspx" />
</definition>
```

Added to web.xml

```
<!-- Index -->
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

Added to applicationContext-security.xml the following

```
    <intercept-url access="permitAll" pattern="/index/**" />
    <intercept-url access="permitAll" pattern="/login/**" />
```

Yet it still first goes to the login page.

**Question**

1. How can I have the index.jspx page to be the default home page, also when a user is not logged in.
2. Where can I read / get more info on how this works?

I read the "Spring in Action" from Ken Rimple and Googled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add *root* to url list:

```
<intercept-url access="permitAll" pattern="/" />
<intercept-url access="permitAll" pattern="/login/**" />
```

and  revert the other changes

You must take account that you are define rules for *urls* and you can permit access just to a *single page*.

Also assure that user can access to `/resources/**`.

Good luck!